# How do I install DevIL with homebrew on mac?

Tags: macos, gcc, terminal, homebrew, devil

I entered this:

```
brew install devil
```

and got this:

```
Error: devil cannot be built with any available compilers.
To install this formula, you may need to:
  brew install gcc
```

So I reinstalled gcc and got this:

```
Toms-MBP:~ tom$ brew install gcc
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gcc-5.2.0.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring gcc-5.2.0.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Caveats
GCC has been built with multilib support. Notably, OpenMP may not work:
  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60670
If you need OpenMP support you may want to
  brew reinstall gcc --without-multilib
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0: 1353 files, 248M
```

But I keep getting the same error when I try to install DevIL

Comment: Homebrew doesn't use the version of `gcc` you install with it. It uses the version of `clang` bundled with XCode. Have you installed the XCode Command Line tools? What is the output of `brew doctor`?

Comment: I wanted to piggy back off of this post but it looks like it's been abandoned. I've repurposed the question in case anyone arrives here in the future. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166365/trouble-with-brew-install-devil