# Trouble with brew install devil

Tags: homebrew, devil

RGBDSLAM install is asking for `devil`

```
$ rosdep install rgbdslam
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rgbdslam: No definition of [libdevil-dev] for OS [osx]
```

But when I try to install devil I'm getting this:

```
$ brew install devil
Error: devil cannot be built with any available compilers.
To install this formula, you may need to:
  brew install gcc

$ brew install gcc
Warning: gcc-5.3.0 already installed
```

How can I get around this?

Note: I have *xcode* installed accompanied with the *command line tools*.

** **EDIT libdevIL installed** **

for some reason gcc 5 doesn't register when devIL is looking for gcc so I had to downgrade to 4.9.

```
$ brew rm gcc // removes 5
$ brew install gcc49 // installs 4.9
$ brew install devil // works
$ brew install gcc // two gcc installed? this might be interesting
```

rgbdslam still isn't detecting libdevIL though, not sure what the deal is.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, maybe try installing any updates due from AppStore, running `xcode-select --install` again in case you have upgraded OSX, and `brew rm gcc` followed by `brew install gcc` to rule out any update inconsistencies.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Good recommendation, but no luck.

Comment: what does which gcc give you?

Comment: @gurghet /usr/bin/gcc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's some helpful notes from answers.ros.org](http://answers.ros.org/question/225798/osx-rgbdslamv2-install-via-indigo/)

> I set `siftgpu_disable_devil = 0` in *SiftGPU/makefile* and
>   `set(ENV{SIFT_GPU_MODE} 0)` in *CMakeLists.txt* with no avail. I'm
>   still seeing rgbdslam: `No definition of [libdevil-dev] for OS [osx]`
>
> Commenting **devIL** out in *package.xml* put me a little further but
>   into some seemingly OSX specific issues, trying to resolve those via
>   github. Will respond here once I have a solution. Thanks for your
>   assistance.